# What's wrong with my JSONP code attempt?

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a script on the external server I'm trying to get data from.

It's a PHP script called test.php and it has the following inside:

```
<?php
  $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  $parts = parse_url($url);
  parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
  $limit = $query['limit'];
  $return_array["result"] = $limit;
  echo json_encode($return_array);
?>
```

So then I send a call to that server using the following:

```
/* this is included in head */
<script src="http://some-website.com/get-text/index.php?limit=10&q=returnText"></script>

/* in Body */
<script>
  function returnText(data) {
    console.log('result: ' + data);
  }
</script>
```

When you go to that php page by itself, the output is

```
{"result":"10"}
```

But when I run the file that has the JavaScript code I get an error:

index.php?limit=10&q=returnText:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

when you click on the link on the right of this error line I see this:

```
{"result":"10"}
```

With a red-underline starting from the colon and going to the right.

I saw somewhere to make sure that JSONP is enabled, it doesn't seem like an actual server configuration or something.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. In [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), you must wrap the [JSON](http://json.org) in a function call; that's how JSONP works.

   Given your URL, your PHP code's response should be

   ```
   returnText({"result":"10"})
   ```

   Get the `q` parameter from the query parameters and use that in the response as the function name. (The usual name of that parameter is `callback`, although you can call it something else if you like.)
2. You've said that the `script` element calling the PHP file is in the `head`, but the `script` element defining the `returnText` callback is in the body. That won't work with the `script` element you've shown, because the one in `head` will stop all parsing of the page, make the browser wait until it's retrieved, and then only when it's retrieved and run will it allow parsing to continue. That means the `returnText` function *won't exist yet*. It would make more sense to move the `script` querying the JSONP to *after* the `script` containing the callback function. (And you might consider [`async` or `defer`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) on it.)

Comment: When you say "wrap the JSON in a function call" are you saying instead of just echo encode_json($array) I'd do something like echo 'functionname('.encode_json($array);.).; sorry not a good idea to try posting formatted code in the comment section.

Comment: Oh man that was dumb with the order of the script/function, thanks I will try your suggestions.

Comment: aaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhh I MADE IT WORK! thank you sir. At least I think I did. I didn't even have to put the "callback" in the parameter. I just echoed the function name concatenated with the json_encode line. This is farther than I've gotten thank you.